# Is the a way to modify the squares in the corners by circles in a QR?

Tags: swift, qr-code

I have followed this tutorial (https://medium.com/@dominicfholmes/generating-qr-codes-in-swift-4-b5dacc75727c) to generate qr, but I am trying to generate customized qr and one of the requirements is that instead of being squares they are circles in the corners. This is possible?

```
func generateQR(fromString : String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = fromString.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
    // Get a QR CIFilter
    guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil}
    // Input the data
    qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    // Get the output image
    guard let qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return nil}
    // Scale the image
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
    let scaledQrImage = qrImage.transformed(by: transform)
    // Invert the colors
    guard let colorInvertFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") else { return nil}
    colorInvertFilter.setValue(scaledQrImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    guard let outputInvertedImage = colorInvertFilter.outputImage else { return nil}
    // Replace the black with transparency
    guard let maskToAlphaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIMaskToAlpha") else { return nil}
    maskToAlphaFilter.setValue(outputInvertedImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    guard let outputCIImage = maskToAlphaFilter.outputImage else { return nil}
    // Do some processing to get the UIImage
    let context = CIContext()
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputCIImage, from: outputCIImage.extent) else { return nil}
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    return processedImage
}
```

There is an example of expected result

https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/img/qrcode-logo.png

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used the Core Image QR code generator filter, `CIQRCodeGenerator`. Looking at the docs, it only takes a couple of parameters, `inputMessage` and `inputCorrectionLevel`. There's no facility other than those parameters to customize the QR code it generates.

I guess you could do image processing on the resulting image to find the "bullseye" corner squares to change them to rounded rectangles, but that would be a fair challenge.

Conversely you could always write your own QR code rendering library. The image processing part isn't that complicated. It's figuring out the QR code standard and how to generate the dot pattern that would be hard. I haven't looked up the specs for QR codes but it's public.

You might take an existing open source QR code library and modify it to create the rounded rectangle corner squares you are after. I think this is the option I would pursue if it was my task. With any luck you can find a well-written library that first generates the QR code as a grid of booleans, and then uses a separate function to render that grid of boons into an image.